# Responsive menu with CSS only doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I'm working on a css+jquery responsive menu, I have a checkbox with text (a '+' symbol that turns into a 'x' after clicked) that shows the menu, however for some reason the checkbox disapears after I click it making impossible to close the menu, I would like to fix this.

Here's the html:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="toggle">
      <input type="checkbox" id="hacky-input">
      <label for="hacky-input">
                        <div class="crossRotate">+</div>
                    </label>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

and the css:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

header {
  height: 12vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    float: right;
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #hacky-input {
    display: none;
  }
  .crossRotate {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-size: 60px;
    width: 5px;
    color: rgb(0, 166, 231);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
  }
  #hacky-input:checked+label .crossRotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .active {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.crossRotate').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggleClass('active');
  })
})
```

[Heres the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahzep/a8nc2jpm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotate mark didn't disappear. It was being moved over to the top side of your page.
The problem is here:

Your `<header>` element has limited height `12vh`.
When your `ul` list is `active`, the height of `nav` is bigger than your `<header>` element.
At the same time, you ask the elements in `nav` tag to aligned in column direction and `space-around`, which makes the exceeded part overflow to the top side, so you can't see it.

The workaround is simply removing the `justify-content` in your `nav` CSS.

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This should work, try it.

Comment: Simply removing the limited height also fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that the cross is being push outside the boundaries by the `ul` element. If you were to add `position:absolute` to it, the cross would remain in the same place when the menu opens. Another way would be to change your header height, so that all elements can fit in it. I made the height change (`height: auto;`) in the code below, so that you can see the result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.crossRotate').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggleClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

header {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    float: right;
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #hacky-input {
    display: none;
  }
  .crossRotate {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-size: 60px;
    width: 5px;
    color: rgb(0, 166, 231);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
  }
  #hacky-input:checked+label .crossRotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .active {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
  }
  ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="toggle">
      <input type="checkbox" id="hacky-input">
      <label for="hacky-input">
                        <div class="crossRotate">+</div>
                    </label>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```